# jQuery minitabs plugin - selecting a tab programatically at page load?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the wonderfully lightweight jQuery minitabs plugin from:

http://code.google.com/p/minitabs/

which is a lovely simple tab system.

However, I'm struggling to set (in the load event) which tab to show by default.
In one of my tabs I have a search form - and if there's a form error I want to reload the page, with the right tab shown to display the errors.

Looking at the code (not a jquery/javascript expert) it looks like all that controls which tab is visible is the class on the tab of 'current' and the tab having display: none removed...

Can anyone with more JS knowledge spot the 'best' way to set the tab to be shown in the load event?

Thanks!
Steve

```
jQuery.fn.minitabs = function(speed,effect) {
  var id = "#" + this.attr('id');
  $(id + ">DIV:gt(0)").hide();
  $(id + ">UL>LI>A:first").addClass("current");
  $(id + ">UL>LI>A").click(
    function(){
      $(id + ">UL>LI>A").removeClass("current");
      $(this).addClass("current");
      $(this).blur();
      var re = /([_\-\w]+$)/i;
      var target = $('#' + re.exec(this.href)[1]);
      var old = $(id + ">DIV");
      switch (effect) {
        case 'fade':
          old.fadeOut(speed).fadeOut(speed);
          target.fadeIn(speed);
          break;
        case 'slide':
          old.slideUp(speed);  
          target.fadeOut(speed).fadeIn(speed);
          break;
        default : 
          old.hide(speed);
          target.show(speed)
      }
      return false;
    }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger click method of desired link after initializing minitabs like this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/cefjE/));

```
$('#container').minitabs();
$('#container>ul>li>a').eq(1).trigger('click');
```

Or if you don't mind altering the original minitabs script see below.

```
jQuery.fn.minitabs = function(index,speed,effect) {
  var id = "#" + this.attr('id');
  var $divs = $(id + ">DIV");
  $divs.not($divs.eq(index)).hide();
  $(id + ">UL>LI>A").eq(index).addClass("current");
  $(id + ">UL>LI>A").click(
    function(){
      $(id + ">UL>LI>A").removeClass("current");
      $(this).addClass("current");
      $(this).blur();
      var re = /([_\-\w]+$)/i;
      var target = $('#' + re.exec(this.href)[1]);
      var old = $(id + ">DIV");
      switch (effect) {
        case 'fade':
          old.fadeOut(speed).fadeOut(speed);
          target.fadeIn(speed);
          break;
        case 'slide':
          old.slideUp(speed);  
          target.fadeOut(speed).fadeIn(speed);
          break;
        default :
          old.hide(speed);
          target.show(speed)
      }
      return false;
    }
 );
}
```

This way you can set up minitabs with predefined `index`;

```
$('#container').minitabs(1);
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/cefjE/1/)

Comment: thank you so much - can't get away with modifying the plug in in this case, but the trigger method worked perfectly... Really appreciate the pointer.